# blackscreen when i boot into ubuntu installer

Tags: boot, xubuntu

I am trying to install ubuntu on my acer laptop and when I boot a usb made from start-up disk creator it shows the loading screen for a bit and then it turns to a black screen with the backlight on. but when I turn it off it goes back to the loading screen. this might be because I tried to install xubuntu with live usb but it wouldnt work. so I am now trying to install ubuntu with a usb stick and its giving me the same thing but different loading screen.

Comment: sometimes it will say cant read configurations

Comment: also i will still get pop up messages

Comment: the boot order does not seem to matter

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with USB bootable. This is a known issue with laptops and desktops with graphics card in built in it. When you see the menu with install ubuntu, there is a modified option with TAB. You will see a option `splash screen` remove that and use `nomodeset`, sometimes the splash screen's resolutions conflicts with graphics card. Then it will boot properly.

Comment: This is not really an answer, please provide *details* on how to actually get past the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I apologize about my english, i hope you understand what i'm trying to say.

Maybe your current OS installed on BIOS/legacy mode, while ubuntu installer trying to boot in UEFI mode. To solve this problem, try to set your BIOS to boot from your usb (make your usb as primary boot device) or enable UEFI on your BIOS on boot options. If You can't find the menu, try to rename/delete folder efi on your usb, and reboot your PC, work fine on my Acer aspire 4750z (Windows 8.1 BIOS/legacy) .